# Android: Mangled PreferenceActivity view

Tags: android, redraw, preferenceactivity

I have pretty unassuming preferences screen based on
`PreferenceActivity`. (You can see it in `DroidIn` app) I'm having some
problems with it that I think have to do with redrawing the screen
after updates. Here are the symptoms:

1. `OnPreferenceChangeListener#onPreferenceChange` if I change summary
   of the preference by doing `Preference#setSummary` the new value is
   painted over the old one creating unsightly effect
2. My preferences screen is large enough that user has to scroll.
   While scrolling, the whole screen get all messed up, again it looks
   like view is redrawn (when scrolled) without erasing the background
   first.

Preferences are defined in XML file - nothing funky just some
categories and preferences nested within `<PreferenceScreen/>`

Do I need to explicitly redraw the view? That seem excessive - why
wouldn't that happen by default?
Since this is an existing app - it's build and distributed with v. 1.5

P.S. I also want to mentioned that this behavior occurs in emulator and on G1 in both 1.1 and 1.5. It looks like I need to log it as a bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved!

Turned out that for whatever reason (probably just copying some example code without much thinking) I had this line in my theme.xml
`<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>`. Once I removed it - my redrawing problem was gone